# MATLAB convert cell to vector

Tags: matlab

I have a large cell containing data like this:

```
    '40.30000, 0.'
    '40.32000, 0.'
    '40.34000, 0.'
    '40.36000, 0.'
    '40.38000, 0.'
    '40.40000, 0.'
    '40.42000, 0.'
    '40.44000, 0.'
    '40.46000, 0.'
    '40.48000, 0.'
    '40.50000, 0.'
    '40.52000, 0.'
    '40.54000, 0.'
```

I want to convert this to a vector like:

```
   40.30,0
   40.32,0
   40.34,0
   ..
```

But the cell2mat function fails and I can't find other functions for the conversion. What is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: There's only one way you can get this as a matrix, which is a matrix of strings. That's only going to happen if all your strings are exactly the same amount of characters.

Comment: Is the second value always going to be `0.`?

Comment: Is this parsed line by line? A simpler approach would be to read the file as a delimited file, where `,` is the delimiter in this case. There are already functions to do this in matlab, which automatically gives you the right output.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) str2num(x), YourCell, 'UniformOutput', false))
```

Explanation:
You can't parse strings into numbers using cell2mat. I just found out that `str2num` actually creates vectors from comma-separated strings so that's lucky. Using `cellfun()` I then use `str2num` to perform this operation on all cell items. `UniformOutput` is required as argument because the output data size (x by 2) does not match the input data size. Finally, use can actually use `cell2mat()` on the resulting cell.

By the way, the stuff following the `@` notation is an anonymous function declaration, they're super useful for these kind of things. Think of them like function pointers or lambda functions. [Documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can not convert this cell array using `cell2mat` because your cell array contains strings, not double values which you expect in your array.

You have to parse the strings first to convert the cells to double, to do so you have to use a for loop or `cellfun`.

Answer (score 2):

As [@Adriaan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33791673/matlab-convert-cell-to-vector#comment55350597_33791673) commented, there is a solution if your data are guaranteed to have the same amount of characters (otherwise see the more general version below). In this case you can first convert to a character array, and then let `str2num` do its job:

```
mycell={  '40.30000, 0.'
          '40.32000, 0.'
          '40.34000, 0.'
          '40.36000, 0.'};
mymat=str2num(cell2mat(mycell));
```

Result:

```
mymat =

  40.299999999999997                   0
  40.320000000000000                   0
  40.340000000000003                   0
  40.359999999999999                   0
```

---

A general (for arbitrary string lengths), and more kludgy solution is to convert your string cell to correspond to valid matlab matrix syntax, and again let `str2num` parse it:

```
tmpstr=cell2mat(strcat(mycell,';').'); %'
mymat2=str2num(tmpstr(1:end-1)); %needed to remove last semicolon
```

Result:

```
mymat2 =

  40.299999999999997                   0
  40.320000000000000                   0
  40.340000000000003                   0
  40.359999999999999                   0
```

This second solution will also work if your character strings are not the same length, but can probably be very memory-inefficient for very large cells.

Answer (score 2):

This is a longshot, but in case the file you use have some kind of standard format this will work. Then you can use another approach when parsing the data. Instead of reading line-by-line you can use the function `importData`.

In test.txt:

```
40.30000, 0.
40.32000, 0.
40.34000, 0.
40.36000, 0.
40.38000, 0.
40.40000, 0.
40.42000, 0.
40.44000, 0.
40.46000, 0.
40.48000, 0.
40.50000, 0.
40.52000, 0.
40.54000, 0.
```

In Matlab:

```
importdata('test.txt')
ans =
40.3000         0
40.3200         0
40.3400         0
40.3600         0
40.3800         0
40.4000         0
40.4200         0
40.4400         0
40.4600         0
40.4800         0
40.5000         0
40.5200         0
40.5400         0
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for two values in each row? This is a matrix not a vector if so. This code takes the cell and produces a matrix where each row is one row of your cell array converted to doubles. I hope this helps as an example.

```
cellthing = {'40.30000, 0.';
             '40.32000, 0.';
             '40.34000, 0.';
             '40.36000, 0.';
             '40.38000, 0.';
             '40.40000, 0.';
             '40.42000, 0.';
             '40.44000, 0.';
             '40.46000, 0.';
             '40.48000, 0.';
             '40.50000, 0.';
             '40.52000, 0.';
             '40.54000, 0.'};

tempcell={};
scell = {};
for i=1:length(cellthing)
    tempcell = strsplit(cellthing{i},', ');
    scell{end+1,1} = tempcell{1};
    scell{end,2} = tempcell{2};
end
smat = str2double(scell);
```

smat is a 13x2 double. I hope that is what you meant.